# How to replace parent view with child route component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have a Vue routes setup with the following parent and child routes:

```
{
    path: '/dashboard', component: dashboard,
    children: [
        {
            path:'report', component: report
        }
    ]
},
```

And in the parent component I have some card menus to navigate to the child component and also a router-view:

```
<template>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row mt-0 h-100">
            <!-- menu item-->
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 my-auto" id="report-card">
                <router-link to="/dashboard/report" class="card2">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                        <div class="card-icon p-3">
                            <img :src="icons[0]"/>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Make a Report</h3>
                        <p class="small">Make a report of a crime or suspicious activities</p>
                    </div>
                </router-link>
            </div>
        </div>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

When I click on the router link, it does render the child component, but in the parent view.

Is there a way in which I could replace the parent view entirely with the child route instead of rendering or appending to the parent?

Comment: Have it as a separate route instead of a child route

Comment: Yea I did that, but I plan to add a breadcrumb menu

Comment: Do you mean a breadcrumb nav or URL? [This](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#nested-named-views) might be helpful

Comment: breadcrumb nav. So if you select an option from the parent menu, it should render the vue component and dynamically build the menu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the right way to do it but you can use v-if with this.$route.name to check router name and render what you want to render.

For example your router will be like:

```js
{
    path: '/dashboard', 
    name: "Dashboard",
    component: dashboard,
    children: [
        {
            path:'report',
            name: "Report",  
            component: report
        }
    ]
},
```

and you can simply check if you are on parent route or not like this:

```html
<template>
<div>
 <div v-if="this.$route.name === 'Dashboard' ">
    <!-- your homepage component -->
  </div>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
</template>
```